# Add and Remove data from MySQL with AngularJS $Resource

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

Edit:
I'm getting the error to save: Error: [$resource:badcfg] save

And this error to get: Error: [$resource:badcfg] get

I suppose it happens 'cause get() expects an object, and my reponse for both is an array: "[{"id":"1","name":"Computador"},{"id":"2","name":"Impressora"}]"

The code was updated and I added the index.html

I'm really confused about how to treat the data on get, save and delete. Must I do it on php?

---

I have some data on MySQL and want to manage it with AngularJS, but my functions to save, delete and get are not working well, the only one that worked was query().

app.js

var app = angular.module('app',['ngResource']);

```
app.controller("lojaCtrl", function($scope, $resource){

    var Produto = $resource("/loja/produtos/", {}, {
        "save:": {method: 'POST', isArray:true}
    }); 

    $scope.produto = {};
    $scope.produtos = [];

    $scope.getProdutoById = function(){
        Produto.get({id:$scope.codigo}, function(data) { //função get
            $scope.produto = data;              
        });
    }

    $scope.getProdutos = function(){
        Produto.query(function(data) { //função query
            $scope.produtos = data;
        });
    }

    $scope.selectProduct = function(produto)
    {
        $scope.produto = produto;   
    }

    $scope.saveProduto = function(){
        //$scope.products = Produto.query();
        new Produto($scope.inserir).$save(function(data) {
            $scope.products.push(data);
        });
    }

    $scope.deleteProduto = function(){
        Produto.delete({Id:$scope.codigo}, function(data) {
        });
    }

});
```

produtos/Index.php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$banco = "produtos";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$hostname = "localhost";
$conn = mysql_connect($hostname,$usuario,$senha); mysql_select_db($banco) or die( "Não foi possível conectar ao banco MySQL");      

$sql = "SELECT * FROM t_produtos";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);

class Produto
{
    public function __construct($id, $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public $id;
    public $name;
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    $p = new Produto($row['id'],$row['nome']);
    $products[] = (object)array('id' =>$p->id, 'name' =>$p->name);
}

if (isset($_GET['Id']))
{
    $p = $products[($_GET['id']-1)];
    echo json_encode($p);
    exit;
}

if (!isset($_GET['Id']))
{
    echo json_encode($products);
    exit;
}   

/*$data = file_get_contents('http://localhost/loja/');

$objData = json_decode($data);

$sql = "INSERT INTO t_produtos(nome) VALUES('$objData')";*/
```

Index.html

```
<body ng-controller="lojaCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="codigo" name="codigo"/>        
    <input type="text" ng-model="produto.id" name="id"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="produto.name" name="name"/>        
    <button ng-click="getProdutoById()">Get Produto</button>
    <hr/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="produto in produtos" ng-click="selectProduct(produto)">Id: {{produto.id}} - Nome: {{produto.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="getProdutos()">Get Produtos</button>
    <hr/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="inserir" name="inserir"/>
    <button ng-click="saveProduto()">Save Produto</button>
    <hr/>
    <button ng-click="deleteProduto()">Delete Produto</button>  
</body>
```

Comment: what is the error you get when you do insert for example?

Comment: When I try the save, I get the error: "Error: [$resource:badcfg] save" in the console. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.1/$resource/badcfg?p0=object&p1=array This is the link it references.

Comment: On, your console check the network tab. and try to find the response of request.

Comment: that error is because you're receiving a JSON, but you are waiting an array

Comment: Humm, the responde to http://localhost/loja/produtos/?save:=%7B%22method%22:%22POST%22,%22isArray%22:true%7D is the array [{"id":"1","name":"Computador"},{"id":"2","name":"Impressora"}], not the data. I guess I need to insert the data to the database with the $save, but I can't do this at all.

Comment: Thx rahpuser, with this I fixed the error of the save error, but I still can't save the data on Mysql 

'$data = file_get_contents("\index.php");

 $objData = json_decode($data);
 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO t_produtos(nome) VALUES('$objData')";'

The error is on the line $data = "file_get_contents("\index.php");" (SyntaxError: Unexpected token)

Comment: sorry, with what you fix the error ? so you have no problems with the client, you are getting problems server side? Can you update the question with the list of errors you get first, how you solve it and the error you get now? would be easier to help with that information.

Comment: @rahpuser thx for the help. I made some modifications again and the error is the same, please take a look again

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because your resource is waiting an object instead of an array..

The resource is wrong, change it to following:

```
var Produto = $resource("/loja/produtos/", {}, {
        "save:": {method: 'POST', isArray:true}
    });
```

Now you are doing a real 'extend' or overriding the default save method of intances
( the default save method waits for an object not an array, that was the error you were getting )

Try it out..

Also new Producto().$save would do a empty post to the server.. is that what you want? if not you need to pass the values to producto instance
with:

```
new Producto($scope.producto).$save(callback)
```

or

```
var product = new Producto();
product.name = $scope.producto.name;
//... other properties
product.$save(callback);
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: It didn't work but thanks. The problem is that I don't know how to POST my data. Not even get() is working, only query()

Comment: @VictorMelias thanks for accepting my answer but if this answer still don't fit your needs, you sholdn't accept it.. lets continue to find a real solution to your problem..